# How to set a text background with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to flutter but I'm interested in learning it pretty much from the beginning.

Right now I'm trying such a basic thing as changing the background color of some text, but I'm stuck.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {

  final barColor = const Color(0xFFD63031);

  var app = MaterialApp(    
    home: Scaffold(    
      backgroundColor: barColor,    
    ),    
  );

  Center(    
    child: Text('My Text',      
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,    
    ),    
  );
      runApp(app);
}
```

I do understand why the text doesn't show but I've been working on this for days now and I have tried a lot of different things without succeeding, so any help would be very appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 87, accepted):

#### *TL;DR* - (Updated 07-08-2019)

#### Using style property (`backgroundColor`)

```
Text(
  'Some text...',
  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
)
```

#### Using style property (`background`)

```
Text(
  'Some text...',
  style: TextStyle(background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue),
)
```

#### Using a `DecoratedBox`

```
const DecoratedBox(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
  child: const Text('Some text...'),
);
```

---

### Long answer

First of all, welcome to Flutter and StackOverflow :)

That happens because are misunderstand the way you should develop with Flutter.
As opposed to what happens with other architectures where you start in the `main()` function, instantiate your vars/objects and develop your flow from there, with Flutter you start your widget tree from your `main()` function as well, usually with a `MaterialApp` or `CupertinoApp` and fit in all its children to create your app.

So, as an example to get what you want, you must add your `Center` widget as the body of your `Scaffold`  and then give a `TextStyle` to your `Text` widget, providing the property `color`. I gave it blue, but you can give it anything else you want. Thereby, this is your refactored code:

```
void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFD63031),
          body: Center(
            child: Text(
              'MyText',
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              style: TextStyle(
                background: Paint()..color = Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

that will provide the following result

[image: example]

I suggest you take a look at the [Awesome Flutter](https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter) repo where you have a lot of good Flutter content to start with that can really help you out.

Comment: Awsome! Thank you very much for the whole answer. Very appreciated :)

Comment: `TextStyle` has a `backgroundColor` property - you can simply set it, instead of creating `new Paint()`

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk thank you, this have probably been added in the meantime. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple you can set it in `style` property..**

```
Text(
  'My Text...',
  style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.grey),
)
```

You can set this many properties to `text` in **`style: TextStyle()`**

```
{ bool inherit = true, 
  Color color, 
  Color backgroundColor, 
  double fontSize, 
  FontWeight fontWeight, 
  FontStyle fontStyle, 
  double letterSpacing, 
  double wordSpacing, 
  TextBaseline textBaseline, 
  double height, 
  Locale locale, 
  Paint foreground, 
  Paint background, 
  List<Shadow> shadows, 
  List<FontFeature> fontFeatures, 
  TextDecoration decoration, 
  Color decorationColor, 
  TextDecorationStyle decorationStyle, 
  double decorationThickness, 
  String debugLabel, 
  String fontFamily, 
  List<String> fontFamilyFallback, 
  String package
}
```